# VBA Code optimizing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code, but is very slow. Is there a way to improve it? I'm a beginner with VBA and would appreciate your help. What it does is it goes through a table and looks up in each worksheet for criteria to match and give values accordingly. Criteria differ by line in the initial range:

```
Sub TAB_REF_SETUP()
    Dim TC As Integer
    Dim TR As Integer
    Dim C As Integer
    Dim C2 As Integer
    Dim R As Integer
    Dim R2 As Integer
    Dim TC2 As Integer
    Dim TR2 As Integer
    Dim CELL2 As Range
    Dim CELL As Range
    Dim RNG2 As Range
    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim WKS As Worksheet
    Dim a As String
    Dim xrow As Integer
    Dim ycol As Integer
    Dim CEllrow As Integer
    Dim cellcol As Integer
    Dim mincol As Integer
    Dim mfrcol As Integer
    Dim schrefc As Integer
    Dim RBC As Integer
    Dim RTC As Integer
    Dim b As String
    Dim CPC As Integer
    Dim D As String
    Dim AR As String
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
    End If

    C = Range("1:1").Find("Dist Classification").Column
    If Range("1:1").Find("Schedule A Ref") Is Nothing Then
        Columns(C + 1).Insert
        Columns(C + 2).Insert
        Columns(C + 3).Insert
        Cells(1, C + 1).Value = "Schedule A Ref"
        Cells(1, C + 2).Value = "Contract Name"
        Cells(1, C + 3).Value = "Lookup Value"
        schrefc = Range("1:1").Find("Schedule A Ref").Column
        GoTo CellFill
    Else
        schrefc = Range("1:1").Find("Schedule A Ref").Column
        If MsgBox("Ref Tab Exists. Do you want to proceed with further check?", vbYesNo, "Perform Further Check") = vbYes Then
            If MsgBox("This will re-write column ""Schedule A Ref"". Do you wish to continue ?", vbYesNo, "Are you sure?") = vbYes Then
CellFill:
                TC = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
                TR = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                Cells(1, TC + 1) = "Applicable Rebate"
                Cells(1, TC + 2) = "Applicable Rebate Type"
                Cells(1, TC + 3) = "Applicable Contract Price"
                Cells(1, TC + 4) = "Actual Rebate $ for Line"
                Cells(1, TC + 5) = "Rebate Owed"
                Set RNG = Range(Cells(2, schrefc), Cells(Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row, schrefc))
                mincol = Range("1:1").Find("MIN").Column
                mfrcol = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("Mfr Name").Column
                For Each CELL In RNG
                    CEllrow = CELL.Row
                    For Each WKS In Worksheets
                        If Not WKS.Range("1:1").Find("Schedule") Is Nothing And Not WKS.Range("1:3").Find(Cells(CEllrow, mfrcol)) Is Nothing And (InStr(1, WKS.Name, "fort", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, WKS.Name, "report", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, WKS.Name, "data", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                            C2 = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Contract Name").Column
                            R2 = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Contract Name").Row
                            TR2 = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Contract Name").End(xlDown).Row
                            TC2 = C2
                            Set RNG2 = WKS.Range(WKS.Cells(R2 + 1, C2), WKS.Cells(TR2, C2))
                            xrow = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("SCC&Tab").Row
                            ycol = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("SCC&Tab").Column
                            RBC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Rebate").Column
                            RTC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Rebate Type").Column
                            CPC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Contract Price").Column

                            a = "=iferror(vlookup([@[Lookup Value]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & RBC & ",false),iferror(vlookup([@[Dist Mfr. Item ID]]&[@[Contract Name]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & RBC & ",false),""""))"
                            b = "=iferror(vlookup([@[Lookup Value]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & RTC & ",false),iferror(vlookup([@[Dist Mfr. Item ID]]&[@[Contract Name]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & RTC & ",false),""""))"
                            D = "=iferror(vlookup([@[Lookup Value]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & CPC & ",false),iferror(vlookup([@[Dist Mfr. Item ID]]&[@[Contract Name]],indirect([@[Schedule A Ref]])," & CPC & ",false),""""))"
                            For Each CELL2 In RNG2
                                If InStr(1, CELL2, Cells(CEllrow, C), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Filler:
                                    CELL.Value = "''" & WKS.Name & "'!" & WKS.Cells(xrow, ycol).Address & ":" & Cells(RNG2.End(xlDown).Row, RNG2.End(xlUp).End(xlToRight).Column).Address
                                    Cells(CEllrow, C + 2).Value = CELL2
                                    Cells(CEllrow, C + 3).Value = "=[@[Min]]&[@[Contract Name]]"
                                    Cells(CEllrow, TC + 1) = a
                                    Cells(CEllrow, TC + 2) = b
                                    Cells(CEllrow, TC + 3) = D
                                    If Cells(CEllrow, TC + 2).Value = "%D" Then
                                        AR = "=[@[Applicable Rebate]]*[@[Applicable Contract Price]]*[@[case qty]]"
                                    ElseIf Cells(CEllrow, TC + 2).Value = "$" Then
                                        AR = "=[@[Applicable Rebate]]*[@[case qty]]"
                                    ElseIf Cells(CEllrow, TC + 2).Value = "%P" Then
                                        AR = "=[@[Applicable Rebate]]*[@[Total Vol]]"
                                    Else
                                        AR = "0"
                                    End If
                                    Cells(CEllrow, TC + 4) = AR
                                    Cells(CEllrow, TC + 5) = "=[@[Actual Rebate $ for Line]]-[@[Committed - Rebate]]"
                                ElseIf InStr(1, CELL2, "nat", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                    GoTo Filler:
                                Else
                                End If
                            Next
                        Else
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    'Notify user in seconds
     MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Without indenting your code is almost impossible to follow (for us *and* for you!)

Comment: Argh!  You have `GoTo` statements within your `If` statements which lead into other legs of the `If` statement!

Comment: I've indented the code - it might help a bit.  (i.e. help us understand it - not help improve the speed)

Answer (score 1):

**Must do:**

- Uncomment from the top this:
  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

**A good idea to do:**

- Change all `integer` to `long`
- Rewrite it in a way that you do not use goto `statements`. Install this -> http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp and indent. Or as mentioned in the comments, use the RubberDuck indenter.

Comment: Rubberduck's indenter basically *is* Smart Indenter for VBA - it's just a C# port of the original VB6 codebase (with additional bug fixes and 64bit support).

Answer (score 0):

The slowest part seems to be looping through cells. Use this instead:

```
Dim vData as Variant
Dim arrayIndex1 as Long, arrayIndex2 as Long

vData = Range(Cells(2, schrefc), Cells(Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row, schrefc))

For arrayIndex1 = lbound(vData) to ubound(vData)
    For arrayIndex2 = lbound(vData,2) to ubound(vData,2)
        'vData(arrayIndex1,arrayIndex2)       
    Next arrayIndex2
Next arrayIndex1
```

`vData(arrayIndex1,arrayIndex2)` is array counterpart of `cells(row,col)`. By default arrays start from 0, so first `arrayIndex1` will equal 0. To change default value to 1, use `Option Base 1` at the top of the code.

Use `With` statement for multiple identical objects for better code clarity - and when inside a loop, also performance, for example instead of:

```
 xrow = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("SCC&Tab").Row
 ycol = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("SCC&Tab").Column
 RBC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Rebate").Column
 RTC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Rebate Type").Column
 CPC = WKS.Range("1:5").Find("Applicable Contract Price").Column
```

use:

```
With WKS.Range("1:5")
   xrow = .Find("SCC&Tab").Row
   ycol = .Find("SCC&Tab").Column
   RBC = .Find("Applicable Rebate").Column
   RTC = .Find("Applicable Rebate Type").Column
   CPC = .Find("Applicable Contract Price").Column
End With
```

Also try declaring variables like `Dim TC As Long, TR As Long, C as Long` so that declarations are not half of code's lines. Operating system converts `integer` to `long` anyway, so don't use integers. Use for example `Cells(CEllrow, C).value` instead of Cells(CEllrow, C).